# Data structure choice for ngrams upto length 5, when building count-based distributional model

Tags: java, data-structures, information-retrieval, bigdata

I am building a distributional model (count based) from text. Basically for each ngram (a sequence of words), I have to store a count. I need reasonably quick access to the count. For n=5, technically all possible 5-grams are (10^4)^5 even if I assume a conservative estimate of 10k words, which is too high. But many combinations of these n-grams wouldn't exist in text, so a 5d array kind of structure is out of consideration.

I built a trie, where each word is a node. So this trie would be really wide, with max depth 5. That gave me considerable saving of memory. But I still run out of memory (64GB) after I train on enough files. To be fair, I am not using any super efficient Java practices here. Each node has a count, index of word as int. I then have a HashMap to store children. I initially started with a list. Tried to sort it each time I added a child, but I was losing lot of time there, so moved to HashMap. Even with a list, I will run out of memory after reading some more files.

So I guess I need to divide my task into parts, store each part to disk. But ultimately, when accessing I would need to merge these data structures. So I think the way forward is a disk based solution, where I know which file to access for ngrams which start with something (some sort of ordering). As I see it, the problem with trie is it's not very efficient when I go around to merging it. I would need to load two parts into memory to merge. That wouldn't really work.

What approach would you recommend? I looked into a HashMap encoding based structure for language models (like the one berkeleylm uses). But in their use case, they don't need to reconstruct the ngram, so they just hash it and store the hashvalue as context. I need to be able to access the context later.

Any suggestions? Is there any value in using a database? Can they do it without being in-memory?

Comment: I think this is what they mean by "big data."

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use HashMap, it's quite memory intensive, a simple sorted array should be better, you can then use binary search on it.

Maybe you could also try a binary prefix-trie. First you create a single char-string, for example by interleave the letters of the words into a single string (I suppose you could also concatenate them, separated by a blank). This long String could then be stored in a binary trie. See [CritBit1D](https://github.com/tzaeschke/critbit/tree/master/CritBit/src/org/zoodb/index/critbit) for an example.

You could also use a multi-dimensional tree. Many trees are limited to 64bit numbers, but you cold turn the eight leading ASCII characters of every word into a 64-bit integer number and then store that as a 5D key. That should be much more efficient than a 5D array. Multi-dim indexes are: kd-trees, R-trees or quadtrees. The 5-gram-count and the full 5-gram (including remaining characters) can be stored separately in the VALUE that can be associated with each 5D-KEY.

If you are using Java you could try my very own [tree](http://www.phtree.org). It's a prefix-sharing bitwise quadtree. It is very memory efficient, very well suited to larger datasets (1M entries upwards) and works natively with 'integer' rather than 'float'. It also has very good nearest neighbour search.